# How to call $(E\hat{x} - x)^2$?

Tags: probability, soft-question, estimation

Let $\hat{x}$ be an estimation of $x$. Quantity $E(\hat{x} - x)^2$ is called [Mean Squared Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error). How one would call $(E\hat{x} -x )^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the square of the bias.